Diff viewer for YAML files
I want to compare YAML semantically rather than line by line.
Would be great to integrate it in IntelliJ and get a visual representation.
I found several online tools like https://www.yamldiff.com/ which work great, but I need an offline tool.
Does anyone know a diff viewer which is aware of YAML structure?

difftastic, from the homepage it seems to be a perfect fit:

Difftastic is a CLI diff tool that compares files based on their syntax, not line-by-line. Difftastic produces accurate diffs that are easier for humans to read.

It is based on tree-sitter and supports YAML via tree-sitter-yaml.
